# Datetime Formula Field is not working if the month is different in date fields

Tags: salesforce-service-cloud

IF ( 
and (Value( MID(TEXT(  End_of_Shift__c   ),12,2)) <5, Value( MID(TEXT(
  Start_of_the_shift__c   ),12,2)) <5 ),( End_of_Shift__c   - 
Start_of_the_shift__c  ) * 24,
IF 
(and (Value( MID(TEXT(  End_of_Shift__c   ),12,2)) >=5, Value( MID(TEXT(  
Start_of_the_shift__c   ),12,2)) <5 ),
(DateTimeValue(TEXT(DATEvalue( End_of_Shift__c  ))&" 05:00:00") - 
 Start_of_the_shift__c   )*24, 
IF 
(and (Value( MID(TEXT(  End_of_Shift__c   ),12,2)) <5, Value( MID(TEXT( 
 Start_of_the_shift__c   ),12,2)) >=5),( End_of_Shift__c   - 
DateTimeValue(TEXT(DATEvalue( End_of_Shift__c  ))&" 00:00:00"))*24, 
IF 
(and (Value( MID(TEXT(  End_of_Shift__c   ),12,2)) >=5, Value( MID(TEXT( 
 Start_of_the_shift__c   ),12,2)) >=5, 
Value( MID(TEXT(  End_of_Shift__c   ),9,2)) > Value( MID(TEXT(  
Start_of_the_shift__c   ),9,2))),
5, 0
)
)
)
)

the above formula is working if the start time & end time is in the same month however if the end time is in the next month then the formula is returning 0.
Expectation: Start time is 11PM Oct 31st and end time is 1:00 PM 1st November then the formula is 0. Ideal expectation is to give 5.

Can you please help me how to fix this.